# So the List will only display if you click on creating a new item. How do I display the List even after switching views?

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, realm

The list only displays when I click adding a new item. I want the list to stay continually displayed. I am using `RealmManager` for the List and data. The function are all stored in the `RealmManager` file. I think it is the `getTasks()` function that update the list but am not sure. I want the list to stay there after I switch to a different view

Here is the files associated with the List:

ContentView2 - this is overall 'view' of the list

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    @StateObject var realmManager = RealmManager()
    @State private var showAddTaskView = false
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
            TasksView()
                .environmentObject(realmManager)
            
            SmallAddButton()
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    showAddTaskView.toggle()
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddTaskView) {
            AddTaskView()
                .environmentObject(realmManager)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.901))
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

TasksView - this is the taskview file

```
import SwiftUI

struct TasksView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var realmManager: RealmManager
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Task List")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            if realmManager.tasks.count >= 0 {
                List {
                    ForEach(realmManager.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                        if !task.isInvalidated && !task.isFrozen {
                            TaskRow(task: task.title, completed: task.completed)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    realmManager.updateTask(id: task.id, completed: !task.completed)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let taskTodelete = realmManager.tasks[index]
                            realmManager.deleteTask(id: taskTodelete.id)
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }

struct TasksView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TasksView()
            .environmentObject(RealmManager())
    }
}
```

AddTaskView -

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddTaskView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var realmManager: RealmManager
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
            Text("Create a new task.")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            TextField("Enter your task here", text: $title)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            
            Button {
                if title != "" {
                    realmManager.addTask(taskTitle: title)
                }
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Add task")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(Color(hue: 0.242, saturation: 0.432, brightness: 0.401))
                    .cornerRadius(30)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 40)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.901))
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}

struct AddTaskView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddTaskView()
            .environmentObject(RealmManager())
    }
}
```

RealmManager -

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class RealmManager: ObservableObject {
    private(set) var localRealm: Realm?
    @Published private(set) var tasks: [Task] = []
    
    init(){
        openRealm()
    }
    
    func openRealm(){
        do {
            let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1)
            
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
            
            localRealm = try Realm()
        } catch {
            print("Error opening Realm: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addTask(taskTitle: String){
        if let localRealm = localRealm {
            do {
                try localRealm.write {
                    let newTask = Task(value:["title": taskTitle, "completed": false])
                    localRealm.add(newTask)
                    getTasks()
                    print("Added new task to Realm: \(newTask)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error adding task to Realm:  \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getTasks(){
        if let localRealm = localRealm {
            let allTasks = localRealm.objects(Task.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "completed")
            tasks = []
            allTasks.forEach { task in
                tasks.append(task)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateTask(id: ObjectId, completed: Bool){
        if let localRealm = localRealm{
            do {
                let tasktoUpdate = localRealm.objects(Task.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id))
                guard !tasktoUpdate.isEmpty else { return }
                
                try localRealm.write {
                    tasktoUpdate[0].completed = completed
                    getTasks()
                    print("Updated task with id \(id) to Realm: \(completed)")
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Error updating task \(id) to Realm: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteTask(id: ObjectId){
        if let localRealm = localRealm {
            do {
                let tasktoDelete = localRealm.objects(Task.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id))
                guard !tasktoDelete.isEmpty else { return }
                
                try localRealm.write {
                    localRealm.delete(tasktoDelete)
                    getTasks()
                    print("Deleted task with id \(id)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deleting task \(id) from Realm: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you never call `func getTasks()`, so your list is initially empty. Add `.onAppear { realmManager. getTasks()}` to your `ContentView2`.

Comment: I would change the approach. Realm is a live updating database - if an object is added, Realm knows that. So, on app start you should add an observer to your Realm data, then when objects are added, edited and removed, the observer will fire and event and update the view(s). There's not reason to keep calling getTasks over and over - let realm do the heavy lifting. See [React to Changes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/react-to-changes/)

Comment: There is way to much code in the question for us to parse through and try to identify where the issue is. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do some troubleshooting, narrow the code to the part that's not working and include your troubleshooting.